# Fixing position of html element

Tags: html, css

I have two divs in my html page. I want one to remain as it is if I scroll the page. I did-

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="head" style="height:100%; width:100%; background:#ff0000; position:fixed; z-index:1">
            <p>
                Hi
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="main" style="length:100%; width:100%;">
            <p>
                Hello
            </p>
            <p>
                Hello
            </p>
            <p>
                Hi
            </p>
            <p>
                Hi
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But the problem is that 'main' div is already overlapped by 'head'. It is not showing both 'Hello's at all.

What should I do so that initially no one is overlapped until we scroll.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is `length:100%`? It should be `height`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good day. You can add some padding-top to #main. for example:

```
<div id="main" style="length: 100%; width: 100%; padding-top: 40px;">
```

Depending on your #head 's height, you may need more than 40px padding-top.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/thisizmonster/19um6tak/

Comment: Dont worry about it, its just a dummy page. BTW your solution worked fine for me.

Comment: A fiddle with one option to hide the content flowing above head .. https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/ye7grxd0/